# Oracle can I use scalar functions in WHERE Clause? or a NULL issue

Tags: oracle, trim

somehow I get never any results when I call:
 select * from table_1 t1 where t1.c1 IS NOT NULL and trim(t1.c1) != '' ;

trim(t1.c1) != '' part causes problems actually i return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is peculiar in that the empty string (`''`) and `NULL` are the same thing. It is as if you are saying:

```
trim(t1.c1) != NULL
```

Such a statement will **never** be true. Try:

```
trim(t1.c1) IS NOT NULL
```